# Compare field value with Custom Label in workflow rule

Tags: workflow, customlabel, workflowrule

I have a custom label : My_Label which stores a string like `Error1,Error2,Error3`. In my workflow rule I have to check if Custom field F1__c contains any of the error specified in My_Label then fire the email alert.

How can I check in my workflow **if custom field F1__c contains any of the error string present in Custom Label?  Is it possible to achieve without creating multiple Custom Labels?

Comment: does this help? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.usefulFormulaFields.meta/usefulFormulaFields/useful_advanced_formulas_acct_mgmt.htm (see second example)

Comment: I would recommend against using a custom label for this since this isn't what they are for. Different users may have different values for the label based on their language. Better to use custom metadata or custom settings.

Comment: Please do not add irrelevant tags to your post.